# Filtering posts on the Tools page as you can in review

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, filtering, tag-filters

I think searching by tags would be helpful in handling flags easier. I currently work mostly with Android so I could get through more flags faster if I could search through the questions/answers, tagged [android](/questions/tagged/android) or [java](/questions/tagged/java), that have been flagged, since I am more familiar with the syntax, coding conventions, and such of these languages/frameworks.

Of course some items are obvious if they should be closed, flagged, edited, etc. Sometimes, however, it's difficult to know if something is valid in a language/framework/etc, if you have never dealt with that particular thing. Sure, you can just ignore the item if you don't know and that is fine but I think this could possibly make the process go a little smoother.

Comment: Which specific queues are you talking about?  Those where it's particularly helpful *already have it*.  For those that don't, it's generally because there's no real need to filter by tag.

Comment: @Servy I was thinking all of them, really. But especially "Suggested Edits", "Reopen", and "Close". Where do they have them already? Maybe I have missed something when I've been in there... For instance, its hard for me to say if its too broad, sometimes, if I don't know the language they are asking about.

Comment: Reopen and close *already* have the option to filter by tags.  Suggested edits should not generally be editing the content of the posts, as such you *usually* won't need any domain knowledge in the subject to effectively review it.  For those exceptional situations, you can simply skip them, making filtering reasonably low priority.  On top of *that*, the SE queue does have a predisposition to showing you questions in tags you're active in, meaning if there are edits for tags you're active in you see them first, and only see others if there are none in your tags.

Comment: @codeMagic - Click on the little "filter" text to the right of the Close Votes title in the review queue. You can type in tags there.

Comment: @BradLarson thanks, I guess I just never noticed that. And now I won't be able to stop looking at it when I open that page.

Comment: That is definitely helpful. But, in the "Tools" area, you don't think it would be helpful?